# Gnuplot newest version on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, octave

I have Gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3 on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I want to upgrade it knowing that a version 4.6 exist. However, when I remove and install it through package manager the installed version is 4.4. How can I install the latest version? That problem also pertains to Octave. Should I upgrade my repositories if so how? I may need a bit of walkthrough due to my inexperience.Thanks for your help in advance.